# JAXB unmarshal mystery XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using JAXB to unmarshal an XML file.

All I know about the XML file is that it is valid XML.

How then am I supposed to specify a class and/or package to newInstance?

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(??????);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Object o = (Object) unmarshaller.unmarshal(myFile);
```

I did not see anything in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html) that address this issue.

Comment: But, as so often, the really interesting point is: Why do you need to unmarshal it? If you don't know what data it contains: How do you propose to process it in any non-trivial way? -- EVen unmarshalling into a generic DOM tree will require you to have some idea of *what* you have there to permit anything but tree climbing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell JaxB what class to unmarshall to so that it can use the annotations in the class to resolve the hierarchy of the xml. You will need to have a class that is also annotated with something like @XmlRootElement. If you want to parse arbitrary xml you will probably need to do something with a DocumentBuilder or xpath.

See this artical for more info.

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/creating-generic-list-wrapper-in-jaxb.html

I have used something like this to convert arbitrary xml to a class. The any field will actually be a list of org.w3c.dom.Element in which you can get information from.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html

```
@XmlRootElement
class Wrapper {
        /**
         * Everything else
         */
        @Transient
        @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
        private List<Element> any;


        public List<Element> getAny() {
            return any;
        }

}
```

Comment: So the ONLY alternative then is to NOT use JAXB in my case?

Comment: With jaxb serialization you really need to know what the source and the destination are. There is a solution I have used to unserialize arbitrary xml data but it doesn't give you usable objects. You can use the @XmlAnyElement(lax=true) which will take in any type of xml and it converts it to a list of .dom.Element's that you can parse but this is not going to buy you much. You would still need to have a class that has a field that is of type @XmlAnyElement and you would use this class as the argument to newInstance.

Answer (score 0):

In newInstance you must add the class root element that map your xml... below an example

Here an example ..

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Vehicals.class);
        final Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        final Vehicals vehicals = new Vehicals();

        List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
        Car c = new Car();
        c.setName("Mercedes");
        cars.add(c);

        c = new Car();
        c.setName("BMW");
        cars.add(c);

        vehicals.setCar(cars);

        m.marshal(vehicals, System.out);
    }
```

**Vehicals.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement
    public class Vehicals {

        private List<Car> Car;

        public List<Car> getCar() {
            return Car;
        }

        public void setCar(List<Car> cars) {
            this.Car = cars;
        }
    }
```

**Car.java**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@XmlRootElement
public class Car {

    @XmlTransient
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @XmlTransient
    private String code;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

output.xml

```
<Vehicle>
     <Car>
         <name>Mercedes</name>
      </Car> 
     <Car>
         <name>BMW</name>
     </Car>
</Vehicle>
```

For the Unmarshal is the same thing. In my case i added Vehicals as parameter in newInstance method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I fail to see how this helps me?  you are still passing in a Vehicals.class to newInstance.